# Consume message from RabbitMQ as list using pika in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, rabbitmq, pika

I have a list like below in RabbitMq queue

```
[{'id':'10','url':'https://www.google.co.in/search?q=rabbitmq&oq=rabbitmq'},{'id':'11','url':'https://www.google.co.in/search?q=python&oq=python'}]
```

while consuming this message, I am getting this message like below as string but not as list

```
"[{'id':'10','url':'https://www.google.co.in/search?q=rabbitmq&oq=rabbitmq'},{'id':'11','url':'https://www.google.co.in/search?q=python&oq=python'}]"
```

I tried to convert this string to list using `ast.literal_eval(my_list)` but getting `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`

How can I get/convert this RabbitMQ message as list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the steps to do that:

1. Use double quote for json array `"`
2. Use json module

> `import json`
>
> `text = "[{'id':'10','url':'https://www.google.co.in/search?q=rabbitmq&oq=rabbitmq'},{'id':'11','url':'https://www.google.co.in/search?q=python&oq=python'}]"`
>
> `text2 = text.replace("'", '"')`
>
> `print json.loads(text2)`

Comment: I have tried this but getting the following error
`ValueError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 22 (char 21)`. Any solution for this?

Comment: It works for me. Thanks a lot. My bad, I have made mistake in the input.